# Sequelize MySQL update value copy from other table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a controller that will do something like this:

```
UPDATE bankapplication_accounts
SET last_successful_logged = last_present_logged
WHERE id = 1
```

My controller in sequelize looks like this:

```
exports.updateLastLoggedDate = (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      id: req.params.userId,
    },
  }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      User.update(
        {
          last_successfull_logged: user.last_present_logged,
        },
        { where: { id: req.params.userId } },
      ).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send('logout correct');
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Can this controller write better?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sequelize.js`, but I think `req.params.userId` should be `user.id`, or maybe it's possible to direct update use the `user` object?

Comment: and this request does not look like **logout** to me...

Comment: I think this is fine. If you like to try some alternate solution, configure setter or custom method for User model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways

1:

```
exports.updateLastLoggedDate = (req, res) => {
User.findOne({
    where: {
      id: req.params.userId,
    },
  }).then((user) => {
    if (user) {
      user.update({
          last_successfull_logged: user.last_present_logged,
        }).then(() => {
        res.status(200).send("logout correct");
      });
    }
  });
};
```

2:

```
User.update(
    {
       last_successfull_logged: user.last_present_logged,
    }, /* set attributes' value */
    {
        where: {
             id: req.params.userId,
          },
     }, /* where criteria */
  ).then(() => {
    res.status(200).send("logout correct");
  });
```